# How can I uninstall package from anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, environment, google-translate

I tried to uninstall "googletrans" from anaconda.

> conda list

googletrans               3.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi

> conda uninstall googletrans

And here is error

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - googletrans
```

Why I can not uninstale googletrans from anaconda?

Comment: Not enough here to go on, but you could try using verbose `-v` for more detail. Also for the `conda list` command, it will describe which environment in the first line of output. It is possible there is a mismatch between the env used for `list` and for `uninstall`. Edited from those in the output would also improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [official documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#removing-packages)

> To remove a package such as SciPy in an environment such as myenv:
>
> ```
> conda remove -n myenv scipy
> ```
>
> To remove a package such as SciPy in the current environment:
>
> ```
> conda remove scipy
> ```

In your case, you could try:

```
conda remove googletrans
```